# Cannot click an link using click() event

Tags: html, vba

I am trying to click a link within an unordered list. The unordered list is within frames and I am not exactly sure of the frame name, so I used a recursive search (code obtained from this forum),

```
Dim elem2 As Object
Set elem2 = FindInputByName(ie.document, "0/2")
If Not elem2 Is Nothing Then
    elem2.Click 'THIS IS NOT WORKING
End If

  Function FindInputByName(document As Object, name As String) As Object
  Dim i As Integer, subdocument As Object, elem As Variant
  Set FindInputByName = Nothing

  For i = 0 To document.frames.Length - 1
    Set subdocument = document.frames.Item(i).document
    Set FindInputByName = FindInputByName(subdocument, name)
    If Not FindInputByName Is Nothing Then Exit Function
  Next i

  For Each elem In document.getElementsByTagName("a")
    If elem.ID = name Then
      Set FindInputByName = elem
      Exit Function
    End If
  Next elem

End Function
```

Using this code no 'click' is carried out. 
Instead of click, I tried `elem2.Focus elem2.FireEvent ("tree[i].onclick")`, then  the link gets selected but there is no click again.

the html snippet is,

```html
<a id="0/2" style="padding-left: 13px;" href="#">GENERAL INFORMATION</a>
```

But the element has a click event 'tree[i].onclick' . **So what should I do to click the link**?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After adding 'application.wait', on click is getting executed